# How to find the history of installation and uninstallation of pip?

Tags: python, pip, dependencies, conda

Today I added some packages to my conda virtual environments, but unfortunately, some of the packages have problem of dependency, leading to many packages version changing.

I have tried to see how to reverse with conda, but I haven't back up the environment and packages version.

```bash
$ conda list --revisions
2024-01-21 19:17:03  (rev 0)
    +_libgcc_mutex-0.1 (defaults/linux-64)
    +_openmp_mutex-5.1 (defaults/linux-64)
    +bzip2-1.0.8 (defaults/linux-64)
    +ca-certificates-2023.12.12 (defaults/linux-64)
    +ld_impl_linux-64-2.38 (defaults/linux-64)
    +libffi-3.4.4 (defaults/linux-64)
    +libgcc-ng-11.2.0 (defaults/linux-64)
    +libgomp-11.2.0 (defaults/linux-64)
    +libstdcxx-ng-11.2.0 (defaults/linux-64)
    +libuuid-1.41.5 (defaults/linux-64)
    +ncurses-6.4 (defaults/linux-64)
    +openssl-3.0.12 (defaults/linux-64)
    +pip-23.3.1 (defaults/linux-64)
    +python-3.10.13 (defaults/linux-64)
    +readline-8.2 (defaults/linux-64)
    +setuptools-68.2.2 (defaults/linux-64)
    +sqlite-3.41.2 (defaults/linux-64)
    +tk-8.6.12 (defaults/linux-64)
    +tzdata-2023d (defaults/noarch)
    +wheel-0.41.2 (defaults/linux-64)
    +xz-5.4.5 (defaults/linux-64)
    +zlib-1.2.13 (defaults/linux-64)
```

I also tried this as an answer said

```py
import pip, os, time

for package in pip.get_installed_distributions():
    print ("%s: %s" % (package, time.ctime(os.path.getctime(package.location))))
```

but there's still some errors:

```bash
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/ac/test/rev.py", line 3, in <module>
    for package in pip.get_installed_distributions():
AttributeError: module 'pip' has no attribute 'get_installed_distributions'
```

Answer (score 0):

According to [someone who posted on the github issues page for pip](https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/5243#issuecomment-381513000):

> You can use pkg_resources.working_set for getting the same information. It's part of setuptools, which is probably already installed on your system. That is a supported way for getting the exact same information. Using pip's internal functions is not supported.

```py
import pkg_resources

dists = [d for d in pkg_resources.working_set]
# Filter out distributions you don't care about and use.
```

Comment: No need to rely on external 3rd party `pkg_resources` (part of *setuptools*), when there is [`importlib.metadata`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/importlib.metadata.html) in Python's standard library.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but I tried as your answer said. It can only show the history of installation, but no history of uninstallation or upgrading. So I cannot see what packages are upgraded because of my wrong operation.